# Question about bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
I have written a basic bash file which automatically logs me into my SSH server. Is there a way to add a message which says "Connection failed" if SSH can't reach the server? Possibly an `if` command? I have put the file on [GitHub.](https://github.com/runnerbeany/urban-funicular/blob/master/s.sh)

Added script

```
#!/bin/sh
#I wrote this little bash script for people.
#It's just for people that don't know how to make an auto login script for SSH.
clear
echo "Welcome, $USER !"
echo "Connecting to SSH server..."
sshpass -p "passwordhere" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host
```

Comment: Post your script. `ssh ... || printf "Connection failed"`

Comment: It's [here.](https://github.com/runnerbeany/urban-funicular/blob/master/s.sh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sshpass -p "passwordhere" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host`, make it

```
if $(sshpass -p "passwordhere" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host); then echo "Success!"; else echo "Bother.  Didn't work."; fi
```